# Присвоить массиву GameObject[] какой-либо GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! 
У меня есть первый массив gameobject'ов (firstArr), где изначально лежат gameobject'ы с тегом Point и именами **Point n** (где n от 1 до 9).
 
Мне нужно, чтобы во втором массиве (way) все gameobject'ы располагались по возрастанию чисел **n**
Мне в голову пришел данный способ, но не идет присваивание во второй массив way.
1) Почему не присваивает? Выдает даннную ошибку. Как пофиксить?
2) Может кто-нибудь предложит иной способ сортировки.

```
j=1;
while (way.Length!= firstArr.Length)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < firstArr.Length; n++)
            {
                if (firstArr[n].name == $"Point {j}")
                {
/тут ошибка         way[n] = firstArr[n];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Вам ошибка говорит, что вы вышли за пределы массива. Проверяйте размер одного и второго массива. И почему массивы? Я пойму да, если уйма объектов, нужна скорость, но небольшой массив объектов..., почему не просто `List<Point>`? Удобство в разы выше, чем простые массив. 2. Сортировка... Возьмите LINQ - `var sortArr = firstArr.OrderBy(x=>x.n);`. Условие сами подставляйте, я не понимаю какая у вас там структура.

Comment: Массив состоит из ссылко на обьекты. Поэтому присваиваете `way = firstArr` и используйте банальный метод сортировки пузырьком, сравнивая последние цифры в имени.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо! Ваш совет по поводу List<>  и OrderBy () сработал!